# What is the most jquery-y way to get the numeric position of an element in a list?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the index of an item in a list like similar to this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li class="selected">Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
</ul>

// doesn't work
var selected = #('ul#options li').index('.selected');
// selected should == 1
```

I could do it with

```
var selected = -1;

$('ul#options li').each(function(a, li){
    if($(li).hasClass('selected')){
        selected = $(li).parent().children().index(li);
    }
});
// selected == 1
```

but it seems like there has to be a cooler/more concise way to accomplish this.

EDIT:

I came up with

```
$('ul#options li').index($('ul#options li.selected'));
```

which is better. It turns out .index() needs an object not just a selector string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var selected = $('ul li.selected').index(); // 1
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/sNQgT/).

The index is 0 based, so the second item is index of `1`.

Getting the index in old versions of jQuery was convoluted, but it is rather simple now. :)

Comment: Answered like lightning while I was still messing with the question! Thanks for the jsFiddle heads-up.

Comment: FYI : This works fine in 1.5 but fails < 1.4.2 - Use mcgrailm's solution for earlier jQuery versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
var selected = $('ul li').index($('.selected'));
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/V8ysY/)

Comment: I think the $('.selected') object has to do a full search. However, it does work < 1.4.2